# SQL Server 2012 Fails to Install with 0x80004005 - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 Express SP4 with Advance Tools on Win Server 2012 R2 Essentials. It keeps failing in the SqlEngineConfigAction_install_startup_Cpu64 action. It fails with error code 0x80004005, the The system cannot find the file specified.

From analysis of the Detail log it seems to fail on

```
(01) 2019-09-20 16:26:58 SQLEngine: : SQLWriter: Starting Writer Service.
(01) 2019-09-20 16:26:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to start service SQLWriter
(01) 2019-09-20 16:26:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open SC Manager
(01) 2019-09-20 16:26:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open service handle for service SQLWriter
(01) 2019-09-20 16:26:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to close service handle for service SQLWriter
(01) 2019-09-20 16:26:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to close SC Manager
(01) 2019-09-20 16:26:58 Slp: Configuration action failed for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst during timing Startup and scenario Startup.
(01) 2019-09-20 16:26:58 Slp: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I cannot seem to find reference to the actual file it is failing on or why it is failing, The Installer has been run as Administrator and also I've tried extracting the installer and running the setup program from an Administrator command prompt.

It fails in the same place each time. I am having to use the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the database service account as the known issue of "Could not find database engine startup handle"

The server is acting as a DC, we have the same version of SQL installed on other machines that are acting as a DC

Can anyone help me please with resolving this issue. 
Full Detail Log is here [Detail.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AXjz3_Ce-FQLBoFOgtl6AIihNKIatAi1)

The machine also has a older install of SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition that cannot be removed. I don't know if this is causing the problem. I have tried both the 64Bit and 32Bit install of SQL they both fail at the same point.

Thanks.

Comment: If you aren't running the setup from a local drive I recommend trying that.  I'm not too certain, but it seems I've seen something like this when running from a network share due to security settings or something if that nature.

Comment: You also might want to try a new download of the setup files...

Comment: Installing SQL Server on Domain Controller is not supported and should not be done. Having said that this should not be the reason for it to fail. I believe the old compact edition may be causing issue. Also is your server windows server 32 bit or 64 bit. Also read [You may encounter problems when installing SQL Server on a domain controller](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2032911/you-may-encounter-problems-when-installing-sql-server-on-a-domain-cont)

Comment: The setup was being ran from a sub folder of the OS drive, the setup was downloaded and extracted.   I also believe that it is the compact edition that is causing the issue. 

The IT manager of the system SQL is being installed on is setting up a dedicated PC to host SQL Server, 

Thanks for the replies.